# MergeSort printing out weird numbers! Can't track in debugging

Tags: c++, mergesort

I've made a MergeSort function but it prints strange numbers. When I pass in int arr[12]={5,3,2,7,6,8,9,6,3,5,2,1}; I get "123500085000". I tried to track my Array in the debugger, but am a bit inexperienced with it. When I "watch" the array variable, the value turns to the adress when it gets passed into the function. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what is going wrong with my function?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



void merge(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int leftStart = low;
    int rightStart = mid+1;
    int auxIndex = low;
    int start = low;

while(leftStart<=mid && rightStart<= high)
{
    if(arr[leftStart]>=arr[rightStart])
    {
        aux[auxIndex++] = arr[rightStart++];
    }
    else
        aux[auxIndex++] = arr[leftStart++];
}
if(leftStart>mid)
{
    for(;rightStart<=high; rightStart++)
    {
        aux[auxIndex] = arr[rightStart];
    }
}
if(rightStart>high)
{
    for(;leftStart<=mid; leftStart++)
    {
        aux[auxIndex] = arr[leftStart];
    }
}
for(; start <= high; start++)
    arr[start]=aux[start];
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int aux[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low<high)
    {
    mid=(low+high)/2;
    mergeSort(arr, aux, low, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, aux, mid+1, high);
    merge(arr,aux, low, mid, high);
    }
}


int main() {
int arr[12]={5,3,2,7,6,8,9,6,3,5,2,1};
int aux[12]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
mergeSort(arr, aux, 0, 11);
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
    cout<<arr[i];
    cout<<endl;
for(int i = 0; i<12; i++)
    cout<<aux[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're supposed to do swaps of `arr` and `aux` entries in `merge`, however you don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: while(leftStart<=mid && rightStart<= high)
{
    if(arr[leftStart]>=arr[rightStart])
    {
        aux[auxIndex++] = arr[rightStart++];
    }
    else
        aux[auxIndex++] = arr[leftStart++];
}

Comment: Is that not swapping them?

Comment: you're not swapping, you're overwriting there.

Comment: see [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in the code lies in the following:

```
if(leftStart>mid)
{
  for(;rightStart<=high; rightStart++)
  {
    aux[auxIndex] = arr[rightStart]; //wrong
    aux[auxIndex++] = arr[rightStart];
  }
}

if(rightStart>high)
{
  for(;leftStart<=mid; leftStart++)
  {
    aux[auxIndex] = arr[leftStart]; //wrong again
    aux[auxIndex++] = arr[leftStart];
  }
}
```

You have to increase the index of the `aux` array. After this correction, I got:

```
1 2 2 3 3 5 5 6 6 7 8 9

1 2 2 3 3 5 5 6 6 7 8 9
```

by adding a space after each element of both arrays.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake. Thank you very much!